# How to get Symfony 4 dependency injection working with two different use case scenarios?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

We're trying to find the best way to implement dependency injection in a Symfony project with a quite specific problematic.

At user level, our application rely on an "Account" doctrine entity which is loaded with the help of the `HTTP_HOST` global against a domain property (multi-domain application). Going on the domain example.domain.tld will load the matching entity and settings.

At the devops level, we also need to do batch work with CLI scripts on many accounts at the same time.

The question we are facing is how to write services that will be compatible with both needs?

Let's illustrate this with a simplified example. For the user level we have this and everything works great:

Controller/FileController.php

```
    public function new(Request $request, FileManager $fileManager): Response
    {
        ...
        $fileManager->addFile($file);
        ...

    }
```

Service/FileManager.php

```
    public function __construct(AccountFactory $account)
    {
        $this->account = $account;
    }
```

Service/AccountFactory.php

```
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, AccountRepository $accountRepository)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->accountRepository = $accountRepository;
    }

    public function createAccount()
    {
        $httpHost = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
        $account = $this->accountRepository->findOneBy(['domain' => $httpHost]);

        if (!$account) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('No matching account for given host %s', $httpHost));
        }

        return $account;
    }
```

Now if we wanted to write the following console command, it would fail because the `FileManager` is only accepting an `AccountFactory` and not the Account Entity.

```
$accounts = $accountRepository->findAll();
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $fileManager = new FileManager($account);
    $fileManager->addFile($file);
}
```

We could tweak in the `AccountFactory` but this would feel wrong...
In reality this is even worse because the Account dependency is deeper in services.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this properly ?

Comment: What about introducing a common interface?

Comment: @NicoHaase How would you create a common interface to a doctrine entity ?

Comment: I don't get that question - a Doctrine entity is a PHP class like all others

Comment: @NicoHaase Then i'm the one not understanding what you mean by common interface :)

Comment: You edit the entity class, and in that line where it says `class EntityXY` you append `class EntityXY implements CommonInterface`  - now, the common classes could rely on that interface, and both changing classes implement the common interface with all common methods

Comment: @NicoHaase Then i think you're saying the same as Marcel. Only it cannot be done on the entity itself but just on the FileManager.

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, you should create an interface for the FileManager and set this FileManagerInterface as your dependency injection (instead of FileManager).
Then, you can have different classes that follow the same interface rules but just have a different constructor.

With this approach you can implement something like:

Service/FileManager.php

```
interface FileManagerInterface
{
    // declare the methods that must be implemented
    public function FileManagerFunctionA();
    public function FileManagerFunctionB(ParamType $paramX):ReturnType;
}
```

FileManagerInterface.php

```
class FileManagerBase implements FileManagerInterface
{
    // implement the methods defined on the interface
    public function FileManagerFunctionA()
    {
        //... code
    }

    public function FileManagerFunctionB(ParamType $paramX):ReturnType
    {
        //... code
    }
}
```

FileManagerForFactory.php

```
class FileManagerForFactory implements FileManagerInterface
{
    // implement the specific constructor for this implementation
    public function __construct(AccountFactory $account)
    {
        // your code here using the account factory object
    }
    // additional code that is needed for this implementation and that is not on the base class
}
```

FileManagerAnother.php

```
class FileManagerForFactory implements FileManagerInterface
{
    // implement the specific constructor for this implementation
    public function __construct(AccountInterface $account)
    {
        // your code here using the account object
    }
    // additional code that is needed for this implementation and that is not on the base class
}
```

Ans last but not least:

Controller/FileController.php

```
public function new(Request $request, FileManagerInterface $fileManager): Response
{
    // ... code using the file manager interface
}
```

Another approach that also looks correct is, assuming that `FileManager` depends on an `AccountInstance` to work, changes could be made to your `FileManager` dependency to have the `AccountInstance` as a dependency instead of the `Factory`. Just Because in fact, the `FileManager` does not need the factory, it needs the result that the factory generates, so, automatically it is not FileManager's responsibility to carry the entire Factory.

With this approach you will only have to change your declarations like:

Service/FileManager.php

```
public function __construct(AccountInterface $account)
{
    $this->account = $account;
}
```

Service/AccountFactory.php

```
public function createAccount():AccountInterface
{
    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  Could you go into a bit more detail explaining how using a FileManager interface will resolve the Account/AccountFactory dilemma as asked in the question?

Comment: This approach seems quite heavy since the FileManager classes would share the exact same code except for the contruct. Also, FileManager is not the only service concerned about this. Many other also depends on this logic. We don't see ourselves duplicating all the classes in the project. But maybe that's the only clean solution...

Comment: @Cerad This resolves the Account/AccountFactory dilemma because of the two different classes implementing the same interface. One will be called for the user level and the other for batch actions. But that seems pretty heavy though...

Comment: Yes, It is not an easy implementation but it looks a better approach. I did an additional comment on the answer that could be also a good solution.

Comment: @MarcelKohls I don't think your additional anwser is possible because it is a doctrine entity. Is it possible to inject a doctrine entity into a service ?

Comment: @MarcelKohls Also i think there is some typos in your last edit so i'm not sure to understand you right